# vb.net findwindowex not working to find child by title

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I know my code isn't that elegant, but it should work, and it doesn't.  Just to give a head's up, I add my arrays to a listbox just so I can see them while I'm getting the code worked out.

```
   cb = New CallBack(AddressOf MyCallBack)
    EnumWindows(cb, 0)

    Dim CadTITLE As String = ""
    For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
        If item.Contains("Program Name") Then
            CadTITLE = item

        End If
    Next

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    Dim Hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, CadTITLE)

    Dim hndls() As IntPtr = GetChildWindows(Hwnd)

    Dim CallTITLE As String = ""

    For Each hnd In hndls
        If Len(GetText(hnd)) > 0 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(GetText(hnd))
        End If
    Next

    For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
        If item.Contains("Call No") Then
            CallTITLE = item
        End If
    Next



    Dim hwnd2 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, nothing, CallTITLE)
            If hwnd2.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        MsgBox("Not Found")
    Else
        MsgBox("Found")
    End If
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I should be able to findwindowex by the window's title, which I have found in the variable CallTITLE (confirmed with msgbox(CallTITLE), but it still isn't finding the child window.  It should return a msgbox("found") and then I can go on to finding the textbox I need.

Comment: Manually trying to fiddle about with windows via these old API calls is rarely a pleasant activity. Have you considered using a more modern approach such as [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: SIGHHHHHHHH.  I was wondering why all the samples I kept finding were in vb6.  I haven't considered it before, looking into it now though.

Comment: Ok, so the computers that we are running this on use an older version of the .net framework (pre-4.5, unsure which exactly).  So, UI automation is out.  Good suggestion though!

Comment: UI Automation works on older frameworks also - at least from 3.5, possibly earlier - MSDN help only shows back to 3.5 because that's the oldest supported version of the framework.

Comment: I don't understand why people continually insist on hacking like this. And no UI Automation does not require 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Always, I can fight with something for hours and as soon as I ask the question I figure it out.  I was missing a level.  MDIClient, should have caught it sooner.

```
 Dim hwnd2 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, Nothing, "MDIClient", Nothing)
    Dim hwnd3 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(hwnd2, Nothing, Nothing, CallTITLE)




    If hwnd3.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        MsgBox("Not Found")
    Else
        MsgBox("Found")
    End If
```